Add colored points to QGIS from CSV file of latitude and longitude
I would like to display on top of various rasters / base maps, a set of points that have fields:

Latitude
Longitude
z

and I want them colored according to the z-value, choosing some kind of color map (exactly as I can do for rasters).
Is there a way to do this?

I now understand how to load the points: I prepare a csv with those fields, and I load it, using EPSG:4326 as CRS.  This displays the points perfectly.  Now I need to color the points according to their z attribute.  How to do this?

Using QGIS 3.38
Add csv to QGIS using 'Delimited Text'

Then Classify [Categorize] the Data based on z values (this is accessed by right click on the layer in QGIS and Symbology)

Source data used (open data) https://hub.ontariobroadbandresourcehub.ca/datasets/eb79317590e24425b939f04b1b7750b3/explore
(added z values) for example only.

Thanks!! This is really a great help for my research.  I had missed not only the symbology, but also that I needed to explicitly click on "Classify" to see any change.
